# min-max-normalized spatial matrix

Tags: r, normalization, spatial

I have a NT-by-NT spatial weight matrix *W*.

```
M <- structure(c(0, 0.758047801675275, 0.555288888514042, 0.209772803587839, 
+                  0.825744792120531, 0.520467817084864, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.692437210353091, 
+                  0, 0.354484270326793, 0.80074916779995, 0.848316900897771, 0.695333346258849, 
+                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.677255709888414, 0.873691915767267, 0, 0.708033675095066, 
+                  0.888929328881204, 0.467107815435156, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.374244809383526, 
+                  0.926736373687163, 0.544780574040487, 0, 0.917211670428514, 0.621895979624242, 
+                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.480277524562553, 0.635059213498607, 0.0919311880134046, 
+                  0.477121754549444, 0, 0.493061222601682, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.314904219238088, 
+                  0.672063720179722, 0.145067517179996, 0.458456297870725, 0.218960420461372, 
+                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0798218175768852, 
+                  0.174890895141289, 0.392556173028424, 0.174170999322087, 0.298141353996471, 
+                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.432126187486574, 0, 0.259547058260068, 0.951727145817131, 
+                  0.278473319951445, 0.815745891304687, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.324105946579948, 
+                  0.222478206269443, 0, 0.93699982133694, 0.671706119552255, 0.864175561117008, 
+                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.322997786104679, 0.347434559138492, 0.663829872850329, 
+                  0, 0.493878246517852, 0.648762248922139, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00411964254453778, 
+                  0.100459286244586, 0.411819625180215, 0.174726587720215, 0, 0.952555304858834, 
+                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7309863534756, 0.774238996906206, 0.356305604567751, 
+                  0.160813542082906, 0.486538449767977, 0), .Dim = c(12L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
+                    c("id1t1", "id2t1", "id3t1", "id4t1", "id5t1", "id6t1", "id1t2", 
+                      "id2t2", "id3t2", "id4t2", "id5t2", "id6t2"), c("id1t1", 
+                                                                      "id2t1", "id3t1", "id4t1", "id5t1", "id6t1", "id1t2", "id2t2", 
+                                                                      "id3t2", "id4t2", "id5t2", "id6t2")))
```

The matrix looks something like this

```
M
          id1t1     id2t1     id3t1     id4t1      id5t1     id6t1      id1t2     id2t2     id3t2     id4t2       id5t2     id6t2
id1t1 0.0000000 0.6924372 0.6772557 0.3742448 0.48027752 0.3149042 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000
id2t1 0.7580478 0.0000000 0.8736919 0.9267364 0.63505921 0.6720637 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000
id3t1 0.5552889 0.3544843 0.0000000 0.5447806 0.09193119 0.1450675 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000
id4t1 0.2097728 0.8007492 0.7080337 0.0000000 0.47712175 0.4584563 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000
id5t1 0.8257448 0.8483169 0.8889293 0.9172117 0.00000000 0.2189604 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000
id6t1 0.5204678 0.6953333 0.4671078 0.6218960 0.49306122 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000
id1t2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.4321262 0.3241059 0.3229978 0.004119643 0.7309864
id2t2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.07982182 0.0000000 0.2224782 0.3474346 0.100459286 0.7742390
id3t2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.17489090 0.2595471 0.0000000 0.6638299 0.411819625 0.3563056
id4t2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.39255617 0.9517271 0.9369998 0.0000000 0.174726588 0.1608135
id5t2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.17417100 0.2784733 0.6717061 0.4938782 0.000000000 0.4865384
id6t2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.29814135 0.8157459 0.8641756 0.6487622 0.952555305 0.0000000
```

Where spatial weights between the same ids W (id1t1,id1t1) is set to 0 (on the diagonal).

Note that the spatial matrix includes two time periods: id1t1 to id6t1 is the connectivity between subjects at time t=1, while  id1t2 to id1t2 indicates connectivity between subjects at time t=2.

My aim is to create a minmax-normalized spatial matrix.

To do so I need to divide each cell of the matrix by *m* defined thus:
[image]

with maxi(ri) being the largest row sum of W and maxi(ci) being the largest column sum of W.

Does anyone know if there is a package that performs this? Otherwise does anyone know how I could do this manually?

Comment: Do you need to take time into consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `romSums` and `colSums`:

```
min(max(rowSums(M)),max(colSums(M)))

[1] 3.615018
```

Speed comparison:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  min(max(rowSums(M)),max(colSums(M))),
  fmin(c(fmax(dapply(M, fsum)), fmax(dapply(M, fsum, MARGIN = 1))))
)

Unit: microseconds
                                                              expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval cld
                             min(max(rowSums(M)), max(colSums(M)))   6.4   7.15  12.567   8.05   9.20   90.4   100  a 
 fmin(c(fmax(dapply(M, fsum)), fmax(dapply(M, fsum, MARGIN = 1)))) 103.2 114.70 175.225 142.55 204.45 1499.5   100   b
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
fmin(c(fmax(dapply(M, fsum)), fmax(dapply(M, fsum, MARGIN = 1))))
#[1] 3.615018
```